# How to Highlight Text on Mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, background-color, onmouseover

I have a page that has about 300 links across multiple frames. Every link has an id that corresponds to an id in at least one other frame. I am writing a script that will highlight both links onmouseover. Currently, I can change the text color of both links (see below). I want to change the background color behind the individual word to yellow to make the text appear to be highlighted.

```
<html><head><title>Test</title>
  <script>
    function hey(id)
      {document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
       window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";} 
    function bye(id)
      {document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";
       window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="1" class="word" onmouseover="hey(this.id)" onmouseout="bye(this.id)">hello</a> 
  <a id="2" class="word" onmouseover="hey(this.id)" onmouseout="bye(this.id)">world</a>....
</body></html>
```

How do I change the background color of a link while leaving the rest of window's background unchanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it by modifying `style.backgroundColor` of the link(s):

```
window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

Comment: That did it. I was thinking I was going to have to put that in a CSS with a hover. This is much simpler. Thanks.

Comment: As a side-note: Writing the style specifics in CSS and adding a class via JS may be a good option as you wouldn't need to edit your HTML/JS source files for changing colors.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the edited HTML using Techfoobar's solution. The ids are also changed to begin with a letter.

```
<html><head><title>Test</title>
<script>
function hey(id)
  {document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
   document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
   window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
   window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";} 
function bye(id)
  {document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";
   document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
   window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";
   window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="w1" class="word" onmouseover="hey(this.id)" onmouseout="bye(this.id)">hello</a> 
  <a id="w2" class="word" onmouseover="hey(this.id)" onmouseout="bye(this.id)">world</a>....
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your onmouseover event :

```
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

You need to put the same instruction with your initial background color on the onMouseOut event.

For example

```
 onmouseover="document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'red';" onmouseout = "document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'white';"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `id` cannot be a number only, nor it can start with a number. Edit it, then place this: `document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";` in your `onmouseover` and `document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "black";` in your `onmouseout` event.

Comment: It's working fine with a number only in firefox. Is that just because firefox is being idiotproof? Will this cause me problems with other browsers?

Comment: Yes, most probably you`ll have problems with IE, because the naming convention is not according the W3C specifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the selection .

```
function hey(id)
{
   var frame_2_element = window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id);
   document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
   frame_2_element.style.color = "red";
   frame_2_element.mozSelection = "yellow";
   frame_2_element.body.mozSelection = "yellow";
}
```

this will change the selected text background color , is that the wanted behavior ?

Comment: teckfoobar got exactly what I wanted. Thanks though.